# CSS - aligning items in a fixed responsive navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I want to align items in the right of a top navigation menu, it's a fixed position menu so text-align: right; won't work.

What I tried so far:
for the normal display (computer/laptop) I tried to do something like:

```
.navbar {
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
}

.navbar .menu_items {
     margin-left: 75% /*this leaves a 25% on the right for the menu items *%
}
```

this works fine for a normal display but when minimizing the browser's window, the menu items get stacked in the remaining 25% of the width.

I thought of making media queries for diffrent sizes of screen which is not efficient.

here are my codes:

CSS

```
body, header{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgb(90,80,50);
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(70,60,30);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 1px rgb(70,60,30);

}

.menu-items {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 0em;
}

.navbar .menu-items li {
  padding: inherit;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: inline;
}

.navbar .menu-items li a:link,
.navbar .menu-items li a:visited {
  padding: inherit;
  padding-left: 0.5em; 
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eee;
}

.navbar .menu-items li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(70,60,30)
}
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</html> 

<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="menu-items">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>  
</header>

<div class="body">
   <br> <hr> <br>  <hr> <hr> <br> <hr> <br>  <hr> <hr> <br> <hr> <br>  <hr> <hr> <br> <hr> <br>  <hr> <hr> <br> <hr> <br>  <hr> <hr> <br> <hr> <br>  <hr> <hr> <br> <hr> <br>  <hr> <hr> <br> <hr> <br>  <hr> <hr> <br> <hr> <br>  <hr> <hr> <br> <hr> <br>  <hr> <hr> <br> <hr> <br>  <hr> <hr> <br> <hr> <br>  <hr> <hr> <br> <hr> <br>  <hr> <hr> <br> <hr> <br>  <hr> <hr> <br> <hr> <br>  <hr> <hr> <br> <hr> <br>  <hr> <hr> <br> <hr> <br>  <hr>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Hav you tried `flexbox`? You can set `.menu-items` as a flexbox container with `justify-content: flex-end`

Comment: Thanks it worked, but it adds some margins. I think I can deal with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the nav to `display: flex` and setting the ul to `margin-left: auto`. When items are in a flex context, margin auto on any given side will push them to the end of the box.

```css
.navbar{
   display: flex;
}
.navbar > .menu-items{
   margin-left: auto;
}

body,
header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgb(90, 80, 50);
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(70, 60, 30);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 1px rgb(70, 60, 30);
}

.menu-items {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 0em;
}

.navbar .menu-items li {
  padding: inherit;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: inline;
}

.navbar .menu-items li a:link,
.navbar .menu-items li a:visited {
  padding: inherit;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eee;
}

.navbar .menu-items li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(70, 60, 30)
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="menu-items">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>


</header>

<div class="body">
  <br>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr> <br>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

proper syntax for flex:

```
/*CSS*/

#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;/*not required, default value is row*/
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

but you could also use `float: right;` on the item

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body,
        header {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .navbar-light .navbar-brand {
            color: #ffffff!important;
            margin-left: 30px;
        }
        .navbar {
            position: fixed;
            background-color: rgb(90, 80, 50)!important;
            width: 100%;
            border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(70, 60, 30);
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 1px rgb(70, 60, 30);
            padding: 20px 0;
        }
        .navbar .navbar-nav {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .navbar .navbar-nav li {
            padding: inherit;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            display: inline;
        }
        .navbar .navbar-nav li a:link,
        .navbar .navbar-nav li a:visited {
            padding: 10px 45px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #eeeeee!important;
        }
        .navbar .navbar-nav li a:hover {
            background-color: rgb(70, 60, 30)
        }
        .navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
            color: #fff !important;
            border-color: #fff !important;
            margin-right: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="body">
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In css give the float:right property

here is the code

`.menu-items {
    float: right;
}`